# Change SVG size properly to fit in a specefic size

Tags: svg

I don't know much about SVG sizes but here's my story: I have a carousel on a website that contains multiple logos in SVG format. The Logo's have completely different sizes, some of them are small and others are really big.

What I want is to fit all the logos in a specific size which is width="200px" and height="62px", it's not that I want to change the main SVG size, I just want all of them to decrease in size where they ca fit in those dimensions I mentioned before. How can I do that?

Note: All these SVG's have different code structures when I checked, for example, some of them have the attribute of "Viewbox" and others don't have it.

Comment: probably best if you edit them to all have a viewBox then.